# How to detect which button was used to submit the form?

Tags: forms, cakephp, submit-button, cakephp-4.x

I can't seem to detect a button press in cakephp4. In cake3 it was easy.

In Form I have:

```
echo $this->Form->button('View Data', [
    'name' => 'viewdata',
    'type' => 'submit',
    'class' => 'btn btn-primary'
]);
```

In Controller I have:

```
if ($this->request->is('post') ) {
    .... 
    debug($this->request->getDdata());
    if (!empty($this->request->getData('viewdata'))) {
```

I click the button and I see `'viewdata'=''` so it detects the button has been clicked but its made the value  `= null`? and I can't invoke the button press function of `viewdata`.

https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-buttons-and-submit-elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is not `null`, it's an empty string. So you could for example do a strict check for that exact value, ie:

```php
if ($this->request->getData('viewdata') === '') {
    // view data submit button was used
}
```

Or just check for the keys existence by comparing against `null`:

```php
if ($this->request->getData('viewdata') !== null) {
    // view data submit button was used
}
```